# Problem with the conservation law in Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, momentum, conservation-laws, feynman-diagrams

I have some problem with the virtual particle process as discussed below.

We have some interactions that have real photon as produced particle. We consider a tree level Feynman diagram for it and the interaction is shown in the picture here:
[image]

(direction of time is from left to right)

Here, $u$ can be any particle obeying the usual conservation laws.

My problem is that, if we have conservation of four momentum in upper vertex and we go to $C.M.$-frame of $uu$(real $u$ and virtual $u$) in that vertex, then the momentum of real photon should be zero and this is impossible!

I know that virtual particles don't respect any particular physical relation but I can't see how this would solve the problem. Since, we can always go to the $C.M.$ of $uu$ and it should not depend on whether we have real or virtual particle.

Or is it that we can't go to $C.M.$ if we have virtual particle? What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no center of momentum frame for those two particles. This question is equivalent to asking "how can a photon have momentum in its own rest frame?" And just like in that case, the answer is simply "it doesn't have a rest frame."

We can use a concrete example to show this. Consider the two particles have equal mass and equal but opposite momentum, so in the lab frame they have four-momenta $(E,p)$ and $(E,-p)$, and the outgoing photons are collinear with the incoming particles, with four-momenta $(q,q)$ and $(q,-q)$, where $q^2=E^2-p^2$.

Then the virtual particle has a four-momentum of $(q-E,q-p)$, by conservation of momentum. If you boost the top particle and the virtual particle to a new frame, the momenta are given by:

$$p^\prime=\gamma(p-\beta E) $$

$$p_{\text{virtual}}^\prime=\gamma(-p+q+\beta E-\beta q)$$

$$p_{\text{real}}^\prime=\gamma(p-\beta E)$$

The center of momentum frame for these two particles is, by definition, one where the momenta sum to zero:

$$p_{\text{virtual}}^\prime+p_{\text{real}}^\prime=\gamma(q-\beta q)=0$$

$\gamma\ne 0$, so the only valid solution is $\beta=1$. But of course that is not a valid frame in special relativity.

The key takeaway here is that not every set of particles necessarily has a center of momentum frame. Specifically, a center of momentum frame exists if and only if the four-momentum of the system is time-like.

Comment: Thank you , is there any real relativistic system that we can not define CM?or this happense only if we have virtual particles?

Comment: @a.p Systems containing only photons that are all travelling in the same direction also have no center of momentum frame. It cannot happen with any real, massive particles in the system, since real particles always have future-pointing, time-like momentum and the sum of any number of such vectors and null vectors is always time-like and future-pointing.

Answer (score 1):

The outgoing photons do not necessarily have zero momentum. 
Let $p$, $q$ be the 4-momenta of the incoming $u$ spinors, and let $p'$ and $q'$ be the 4-momenta of the outgoing photons. 
Then, conservation of momenta at the top vertex merely fixes the 4-momentum of the propagator as $p - p'$ (depending on your convention of the direction of the momentum).

However, conservation of momentum imposed on the system as a whole asserts that 
$$p+ q = p ' + q ' . $$
The CoM frame is chosen when the three momenta $\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{q} = 0$. 
So all we have is that 
$$ p + q  = \left(2 \sqrt{|\mathbf{p}|^2 + m ^2}, \mathbf{0}\right) = p ' + q ' $$
where $m$ is the mass of both spinors. This doesn't give us enough constraints to fix $\mathbf{p'}$ as zero.

Comment: I understand what wou say But you consider system as a whole and sit in the CM of real particles, in this view it is appearance that maybe we have not problem.But what about we go and sit in CM of one real u and virtual particle then if write conservation law for 3patricles(u and virtual u and photon)then the momentum of photon be zero,